# indicate automatic line break in white-space: pre-wrap element

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm using `white-space: pre-wrap` style on a HTML `<pre>` element to allow lines to break when they are longer than the browser window is wide.

Unfortunately those broken lines also *look* as if they have a line break at the end; the user cannot see if it was an automatic line break.

Is there a way to show either at the end of the line that wrapping is going on (as emacs does with a `\` character), or at the beginning of wrapped lines that they are a continuation of a previous line (e.g. with `→`)?

Copying & pasting should not copy the continuation characters.

---

[Example code](http://www.bogo/tagebuch/gimp-remove-watermark-lines.htm#final-p2):

```
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap">for i in range(19): selwidth=5; selheight=1000; image = gimp.image_list()[0];posx=initx+i*90; pdb.gimp_image_select_polygon(image, 2, 8, [posx, 0, posx+selwidth, 0, posx+selwidth-selheight, selheight, posx-selheight, selheight]);</pre >
```

Preferred rendering, with a `→` at the beginning of continuation lines:

```
for i in range(19): selwidth=5; selheight=1000; image = gimp.image_list()[0];posx=
→initx+i*90; pdb.gimp_image_select_polygon(image, 2, 8, [posx, 0, posx+selwidth, 0, 
→posx+selwidth-selheight, selheight, posx-selheight, selheight]);
```

Comment: Can't add symbols on line-breaks generated by wrapping text, but you can add `→` https://jsfiddle.net/rv5d5omL/3/ or `↳` https://jsfiddle.net/rv5d5omL/4/ on every line-break `\n`

Comment: This ^^. And regarding *"..copying & pasting should not copy the continuation characters..."* -- you could use a variation of the code given by @Mi-Creativity -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/e9v8audb/ -- This will not include the characters while copy-pasting and also programmatically `textContent` will not include those, keeping it clean.

Comment: this is same @Abhitalks fiddle but with "return" arrow symbol and last symbol removed https://jsfiddle.net/e9v8audb/4/

Comment: But I thought the OP wants to break on code lines ends -*the semi-colons*-

Comment: @Mi-Creativity: Hmmm, I don't think so. Op wants to just differentiate the real existing hard line-breaks with the line-wraps (due to pre-wrap).

Answer (score 3):

**Pre** is intended to keep text as it was typed. It helped keep poems and speciality text as they were intended to be seen and not formatted by the browser. I would think most people will be able to tell a line of text is being wrapped in Pre with whitespace: pre-wrap because it would look something like this:
Five little monkeys jumping on the 
bed, {{line break}}
One fell off and bumped his head. {{line break}}
Mama called the Doctor and the 
Doctor said,{{line break}}
"No more monkeys jumping on the bed!'.{{line break}}

If you went with straight HTML `<p>` it would look as you had typed it in your example and `<pre>` with whitespace: pre-wrap would look the space as you have it typed.

To color the ends of each line you might try putting a `<span>` and give it CSS to color and size or do a `<span>` on the whole sentence giving it a CSS background color.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear that I'm talking about source code. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK not with CSS, instead you can replace every newline with 2 newlines so newlines will be distinguished when text wraps, to do this either manually enter two -*or more*- line-breaks `<br>`s for each new line, or if you can use javascript then you can replace each semi-colon `;` -*because the provided example in the question is code where each line ends with* `;`- replace it with `;\n\n` -*or with `;<br><br>` instead*- thus it will recognized.

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rv5d5omL/2/)

```js
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0],
  preHTML = pre.innerHTML;

pre.innerHTML = preHTML.replace(/;\s*/g, ";\n\n");
```

```html
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap">for i in range(19): selwidth=5; selheight=1000; image = gimp.image_list()[0];posx=initx+i*90; pdb.gimp_image_select_polygon(image, 2, 8, [posx, 0, posx+selwidth, 0, posx+selwidth-selheight, selheight, posx-selheight, selheight]);</pre >
```

Comment: Then source code with normal line breaks has suddenly the double height, which is not what I want.